# how to use bash to write "TOP" like program?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a management utility like "TOP" to monitor some device.
How can I use BASH to write something like "TOP" which means the output is dynamically refreshed and the new output will override the old output?

THanks!

Comment: `while true; do clear; date; sleep 2; done`?

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can use the [`watch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) command:

```
watch /path/to/your_script.sh
```

Write `your_script` in a way that it runs just once, not in a loop. `watch` will call it periodically and update the screen instead of appending to the output.

Comment: `Bash` will run on many platforms where `watch` is not available, that's the point.

Comment: Ok, forget about Windows, but what's with the Apple watch?